# Can ionised ships return fire?

Tags: star-wars-x-wing

In Star Wars X-Wing if a ship has an ionising token can it shoot?

For example:

- TIE Fighter skill 5
- Y-wing skill 8
- TIE Fighter moves
- Y-wing moves
- Y-wing shoots and scores damage with ion cannon

The TIE hasn't fired yet but it's been ionised. Is it still allowed to return fire?

Comment: Considering what happens in Star Wars shows and books when a ship is hit by an ion weapon, it's not surprising that people wonder if ionized ships can perform attacks. It's helpful to remember in X-Wing Miniatures, you don't do anything that the rules or cards don't specifically tell you that you can do. (That solves another common misunderstanding where people think ships normally take damage when they overlap other ships.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: Ion Token reference card]

According to the Ion Token reference card, the TIE Fighter would be able to return fire, as you are in the **Combat Phase**.